# Django validate a python dictionary via DictField

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm new to the django rest framework and have two basic questions about something I don't fully understand. I have a python function which takes as an input a dictionary and would like to make it available via an API.

```
In [24]: def f(d):
    ...:     pass
    ...:
```

I'm testing a post request via postman sending a json file which should be translated to my python dictionary. The input I'm sending looks like

```
{
    "test": {
        "name1": {
            "list": ["a",
                "b",
                "c"
            ],
            "numbers": [0.0, 0.1]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is a dict currently with one key `name1` which itself is a dict with two keys, `list` and `numbers`.

The view set I wrote for this example looks like this:

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(type(request.data.get("test")))
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.validated_data.get("test"))
            f(serializer.validated_data.get("test"))
```

and my serializer looks like this:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    test = serializers.DictField()
```

If I send the json input above I get the printed the following:

```
<type 'dict'>
None
```

So I have the following two questions:

1. As we can see the `request.data.get("test")` is already the desired type (`dict`). Why do we want to call the serializer and doing some validation. This might cast certain inputs to not standard python types. E.g. validating a decimal via the `DecimalField` returns a object of type `Decimal` which is a Django type not a standard python type. Do I need to recast this after calling the serializer or how do I know that this won't cause any trouble with function expecting for example native python `float64` type?
2. How can I define the serializer in the above example for the dictionary so that I get returned the correct object and not None? This dictionary consists of a dictionary consisting of two keys, where one value is a list of decimals and the other a list of strings. How can I write a validation for this within the DictField?